# Инициализация массива хранящего списки

Tags: c#

Долго не мог понять почему вылетает ошибка

```
List<Grid>[] набор = new List<Grid>[раздел.Length];
набор[параметр[n].Рзд].Add(параметр[n].ВВД(стиль));
```

Потом додумался что нужно список инициализировать в массиве

```
List<Grid>[] набор = new List<Grid>[раздел.Length];
            for (int n = 0; n < набор.Length; n++)
            {
                набор[n] = new List<Grid>();
            }
```

**Вопрос есть ли способ сделать это без цикла сразу при создании массива**

Comment: типа так? `var myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x=>new List<Grid>()).ToArray();`

Comment: Не используйте кириллицу для переменных и членов классов в C#, это не принято, и код такой читать тяжело и не хочется. Оставьте кириллицу 1С программистам.

Comment: @aepot если есть отличное знание английского тогда может быть. Но если "набор"  я назову "nabor" то это дичь по моему. А что касается сложнее читать, это субъективно, мне наоборот легче понять что к чему относится. Да и на работу программистом я пока что не претендую.

Comment: Любой самый простой транслит лучше, чем кириллица. По коду - оставьте цикл, это нормальная история. Если кажется громоздским, вынесите в отдельный метод. Разбивать код на методы - хорошо.